# Расположение иконок в Head NavigationView

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

Добрый день. Использую стандартный гугловский DrawerLayout и в нём NavigationView. Появился вопрос, как правильно расположить иконки в Head NavigationView, чтобы на устройствах с разным размером экрана иконки располагались более-менее симметрично и одинаково. 
Если всего 2 иконки, их можно сделать симметрично используя отступ от левого/правого края.
Если всего 3 иконки, их можно сделать симметрично используя расположения отступа от левого края/по центру/от правого края

**Проблема:** Как расположить 4(и более) иконки ровно по центру, с одинаковым отступом от краёв лайаута и одинаковым отступом друг от друга. Вот фото, чтобы было понятнее, что я имею ввиду:

[image: пример вопроса]

Вот мой лэйаут хэдэра, здесь крайние всегда одинаково отображаются, а центральные в зависимости от размера экрана, т.е. по-разному:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_head"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_color3"
    android:layout_height="84dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="84dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="84dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/im_b1"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_main"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
             />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/im_b2"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_kalend"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/im_b1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/im_b1"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/im_b3"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_galochka"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/im_b4"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/im_b4"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"


            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/im_b4"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_setting"

           android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
             />
    </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/nd_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#4Dffffff"

            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="27dp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```